# Activation function with exponential distributed data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am in beginning of neural networks, I have a bunch of targets in a regression model to predict, what I have noticed is the model works perfectly with targets were already normally distributed, but it does not work well with exponentially distributed targets, I understand this is the activation function rule, but I have been trying many functions (relu, linear, selu,elu, etc) and still didn't get a great result.

Please check the images below

```
Normally distributed
```

[image: img_Normally_distributed]

```
Exponentially distributed
```

[image: img_ Exponentially_distributed]

Answer (score 0):

That sort of makes sense, but riddle me this.  Are you taking the right approach?  You don't need to assume Normal distributions to do regression.  It is a common misunderstanding that OLS somehow assumes normally distributed data. It does not. It is far more general.  So, OLS regression makes no assumptions about the data, it makes assumptions about the errors, as estimated by residuals.  Also, transforming data to make in fit a model is, in my opinion, the wrong approach. You want your model to fit your problem, not the other way round.  There are a few ways to deal with skewed data sets.

```
1. Normalize Data
2. Standardize Data
```

Let's see an example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
##iris.keys()


df= pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)


# Normalize the data attributes for the Iris dataset.
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing
import seaborn as sns
# load the iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
print(iris.data.shape)

# separate the data from the target attributes
X = df[['sepal length (cm)','sepal width (cm)','petal length (cm)','petal width (cm)']]
y = df['species']
sns.displot(X)
```

[image]

```
# normalize the data attributes
normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(X)
sns.displot(normalized_X)
```

[image]

```
# Standardize the data attributes for the Iris dataset.
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing
# load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
print(iris.data.shape)
# separate the data and target attributes
X = X
y = y
sns.displot(X)
```

[image]

```
# standardize the data attributes
standardized_X = preprocessing.scale(X)
sns.displot(standardized_X)
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[iris.feature_names], iris.target, test_size=0.5, stratify=iris.target, random_state=123456)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, oob_score=True, random_state=123456)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
predicted = rf.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predicted)
print(f'Out-of-bag score estimate: {rf.oob_score_:.3}')
print(f'Mean accuracy score: {accuracy:.3}')
```

Result:

```
Out-of-bag score estimate: 0.96
Mean accuracy score: 0.933
```

See the link below for specific info on these concepts.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/rescaling-data-for-machine-learning-in-python-with-scikit-learn/

Again, though, maybe this is not the right approach.  For one thing, you can try to apply a different model to your specific data set.  Support Vector Machine algos just cares about the boundaries of the separating hyperplane and do not assume the exact shape of the distributions.  One of my favorite models in the the Decision Tree family, specifically, the Random Forest model.

Also, see this link,

https://www.blopig.com/blog/2017/07/using-random-forests-in-python-with-scikit-learn/